# Is there any reason to actually hurry?

Tags: max-payne-3

I just picked up Max Payne 3 on the autumn sale, and while the game's story does an excellent job of conveying urgency, I always find it hard to resist the allure of collectibles.

As always, finding collectibles is a matter of methodically sniffing around all the rooms, which is hardly something you would take the time to do when you're chasing kidnappers (for example). Will taking my time ever adversely affect my playthrough?

Comment: No it will not.

Comment: very few games will actually need you to hurry

Comment: Human Revolution is the only one I can think of that actually does have consequences for taking too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, no.

However, there are at least two scenarios where you'll end up failing the mission if you don't keep moving:

> The nightclub shootout in episode 2.  If you spend too much time poking around after falling/shooting through the VIP Room glass, you'll fail.

> In Episode 6, after the bomb goes off. If you don't keep progressing through the inferno (at least during the first part where you go through the doors and up the stairs) you'll also fail there as well.

Comment: You don't say. Would you mind listing said scenarios?

Comment: That's the only one I can think of so far (I'm still playing through the game right now); but I definitely remember that spot.

Comment: I also got caught at that spot, but don't remember it happening anywhere else where it's not immediately obvious that you need to get the hell out of where you're at or you'll die.

Comment: In [chapter 12, The Great American Savior of the Poor](http://maxpayne.wikia.com/wiki/The_Great_American_Savior_of_the_Poor) the mission fails if you take too long after exploding the planted bombs.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not to my knowledge. Just like in every other game that encourages exploration (via collectibles, achievements and the like) it does not punish you for it. You can take your time and explore as long as you like.
The only special case in Max Payne 3 are the additional modes like New York Minute, which limit the time available to finish a particular level.

Many games tell you it is utterly important that you do something quickly but allow you to wander around aimlessly for as long as you like. This is quite comical indeed. Another recent example of this is Far Cry 3.

Comment: This is false, see [the accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124038/148510).

Answer (score -1):

Explore as much as you want, it is somewhat part of Rockstar-gaming strategy (what ever we might think of pidgeons and what not).

In the very few cases of MP3, where time is essential, you will have to repeat from your last checkpoint. That's the worst "punishment" for exploring, and its only very few scenes.

Happy exploring :)

Comment: This doesn't add to [the accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124038/148510).